# Does Mineflayer work on Pocket Edition servers?

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to program and test the Mineflayer bot more and it doesn't seem to work no matter what I try for pocket edition lan worlds. Some advice?

Comment: It's not clear how this is within the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [help/on-topic] - can you elaborate as to how this is at all a programming question?

Comment: Mineflayer doen't currently support this. [This repo issue](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/issues/374) may give more information on it.

Comment: @esqew This question is probably better suited in the [discussions](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/discussions) section of the [Mineflayer repository](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer), but it is somewhat related to programming.